# Return value of kill -9 $pid

Tags: linux, bash, process, kill

Suppose if I am running a kill -9 $pid option on a process, and it throws an "Operation not permitted" exception.

Is there a way I could identify this and handle the situation?

eg:

```
return_id=`kill -9 992`
```

Comment: To get exit status : `echo $?` . `0` for successful and `non-zero` for non-successful.

Comment: Ah! that pretty much does the trick! Is there a way to store the same in a variable?

Comment: `kill -9` probably should not be used in a script; it's used to kill exceptionally ill-behaved (i.e. buggy) programs during development, not programs that are running in normal usage.

Comment: @akshayramnath, `$?` is a special variable. You can do  comparison as like any other variable.

Answer (score 1):

Operation is not permitted, is exit code 1-- but that's probably not unique to that error.  You could always check the error message.

```
response=$(kill $pid 2>&1)
if [[ $response =~ "Operation not permitted" ]]; then
   error_handling_function
fi
```